# select query with variables not returning correct results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have the two queries below.

The first query works however in my where condition I've hard coded some values. So in the second query I've put the same values but declared them as variables. However when I run it nothing is returned, which I don't understand?

**First Query**

```
declare @fxPair nvarchar(max) = ''
select @fxPair = @fxPair + '[' + Currency + '], ' 
from myTbl  
where DateH = '2016-11-14' and Code in ('ABV', 'ABG')
group by Currency
order by Currency   
set @fxPair = SUBSTRING(@fxPair, 1, len(@fxPair) - 1)
print @fxPair
```

**Second Query**

```
declare @Code nvarchar(10) = 'ABV, ABG'
declare @DateH nvarchar(20) = '2016-11-14'

declare @fxPair nvarchar(max) = ''
select @fxPair = @fxPair + '[' + Currency + '], ' 
from myTbl  
where DateH = @DateH and Code in (@Code)                -- this line doesn't work
group by Currency
order by Currency   
set @fxPair = SUBSTRING(@fxPair, 1, len(@fxPair) - 1)
print @fxPair
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  With a single variable, `in` is the same as `=`, so your code is really `code = @code`.  And a single code isn't going to match a list.

Comment: `'ABV, ABG'` is very different to `{'ABV', 'ABG'}`

Comment: @GordonLinoff, sorry that was a typo. Code = 'ABV, ABG'

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza sorry what is the difference?

Comment: One is a string, the other is an array/list. `IN` will compare the whole string, wont separate the values.

Comment: for the in condition does it need to be a string or array?

Comment: `In` expects one or more values. @Code is seen as one value, regardless of its contents. You could split the values. In sql-server 2016 `STRING_SPLIT` was introduced and I reckon the following would work: `code in (STRING_SPLIT, @Code, ',')`

Comment: It's not a good idea to store dates as strings, we don't have the `date` datatype for nothing. Use appropriate datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try it like this :

```
declare @code table (code varchar(10))
declare @DateH nvarchar(20) = '2016-11-14'
declare @fxPair nvarchar(max) = ''

insert into @code values ('ABV'), ('ABG')

select @fxPair = @fxPair + '[' + Currency + '], ' 
from   myTbl  
where  DateH = @DateH 
and    Code in (select code from @code)
group by Currency
order by Currency   

set @fxPair = SUBSTRING(@fxPair, 1, len(@fxPair) - 1)
print @fxPair
```